# use a variable from a page in another one

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm creating an app for Windows store using C#. I need to pass a string variable to another page. I have already tried using this variable as an input parameter of the page where the variable is going to be used, like this:

***In the page where the variable was created:***

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainMenu(Variable)));
```

***In the page where the variable is going to be used:***

```
public PageName(string Variable)
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

so, something like winforms, obviously doesn't work to windows store

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a parameter to the `Navigate` method.

`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainMenu),yourVariable);`

and in your MainMenu page you can find your "navigation data" in the `OnNavigateTo` (virtual) method.

hope this help.

Regards

**[Edit]** Take a look at this exemple [Quickstart: Navigating between pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) under "Passing information between pages" for example code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the following event to get the value of the variable out

OnNavigatedTo

Here is the corresponding link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)